# What can't you learn?

Tags: riddle

My first riddle, it's probably too easy though.

You can get almost any knowledge from one book or another, but there is one thing that is absolutely impossible to learn from a book. What is it?

I'm not talking about any physical skill that requires practice.

Comment: @mmking that's a physical skill. I'm specifically talking about knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is supposed to be:

> The one thing that is impossible to learn from a book is how to read.

However, this is not really true.

Comment: You're right! But I do think it is true.

Comment: @RichardRoe http://www.phidal.com/upload/books/big/978-2-7643-1565-1.jpg

Comment: @sven B but you need someone's help with that

Answer (score 4):

One thing that it is impossible to learn from a book?

> Something you already know.